# Is there an app to chat on Facebook on iOS?

Tags: applications, facebook

Is there an app to chat on Facebook on iOS ?

I would like to be laptop free

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two, both from Facebook. It's available in the Messages section of [Facebook app](http://itunes.apple.com/app/facebook/id284882215), as well as the standalone [Facebook Messenger app](http://itunes.apple.com/app/facebook-messenger/id454638411). The standalone app uses a denser interface, and would be an improvement if you were going to use this heavily, but the section of the complete app isn't much worse.

Comment: I see, however both don't show who is currently online...

Comment: @Patrick: They haven't always worked for me in the past, but since I updated to iOS 4 I've got reliable push notifications for messages from Messenger. The Facebook app gives me some push notifications, but I'm not sure which; it's probably based on some settings.

Comment: Push notifications work but they ignore mine and friends online status

Comment: As of iOS 6 push notifications don't work right in the Facebook app.  See this question for details:http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/89947/27661

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use [IM+](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/im/id285688934?mt=8) it's a free app. And if you like to spending some money you can use [IM+ Pro](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/im-pro/id296246130?mt=8).