# iOS6 on iPod: Facebook Messenger doesn't show notifications

Tags: ios, ipod, facebook, chat

I have both Facebook and  Facebook Messenger installed on my 4th generation iPod Touch, and Facebook messenger doesn't seem to receive push notifications. The setting is on in the iOS settings, but it doesn't seem to affect anything.

The notifications for my messages show in the normal Facebook app, but this is the opposite of the behaviour I want. I want messages in Facebook chat to show in messenger instead.

How should I go about fixing this? I'm not very used to iOS so I'm not sure what other places I should check.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to install the standalone Facebook Messenger app (different app in the app store from the facebook app) to get push notifications working with Facebook messenger.  Notifications from the main Facebook app don't seem to work at all for messages.